# Using the find_elements_by_xpath in selenium to find text within web element, always returns the text of the first web element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Below is how the inspector looks:

[image]

I want to get the text of class "info" of each class with style="background-color: initial;". Here is my code:

```
info = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@style="background-color: initial;"]')
for i in info:
    my_text = i.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="info"]')
    print(my_text.text)
```

However, the above code always returns the text within the first web element with style="background-color: initial;" and class="info". How shall i adjust my code to get the text of each element seperately? For example, how to only get the text of class="info" within the 4th element with style="background-color: initial;"?

Many thanks.

Comment: Please post the html as a text, and not an screensot.

Comment: Not sure how to do it on firefox. I tried to right-click on class="market" and then copy inner html, but when i paste the result on an editor, text like style="background-color: initial;" does not exist. I also tried to right-click and select "view page source", but again, the result does not include the text that is inlcuded on the screenshot i sent.

Answer (score 1):

This extra dot solves the issue:

```
for i in info:
    my_text = i.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@class="info"]')
    print(my_text.text)
```